# Sample Product, change location of Price | Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the location of Price of all sample Products from **the current location, which is below the title** to **just about "add to cart"**.
If i do it with CSS, that is affecting the responsiveness of the website.
i want to make this change on a PHP, so that it can impact all the SAMPLE products which i upload now on..
can i make any changes on the PHP so that the "SAMPLE Product" Price always shows up **just above** "add to cart" ?

**at present:**
[image]

**what i need is:**
[image]

**the code in content-single-product.php**

```
<div class="single clearfix  row-fluid">
        <div class="wrap span6 product-left">
            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_show_product_images hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="product-detail">
                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
                    //echo  do_shortcode("[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]");
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, you are overwriting the WooCommerce hook inclusion/priority order. So the price will be included after `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` which has a priority value of `20`

Include the following code in `functions.php`.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );
```

Comment: Is this applicable for only SAMPLE Products ? because i do not need this to impact my variation product's single product page.

Comment: You can use [Conditional tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) around the code. I think `if ( is_product_category( 'sample-products' ) ) { };` can work fine for you.

Comment: Hope you are well, i am facing a issue with header.php, i have asked a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678319/header-php-change-position-of-search , no one has answered it yet.. request your help ..

Answer (score 0):

**WooCommerce** displays the `price between the product title and product description` on the **single product page** by default.

`If you’d like to move the price after the content`, you can do so easily by adding the following hook to your theme’s **functions.php** file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );
```

By changing the number from 10 to 25, you move the price below the single excerpt (which has a priority of 20).

The WooCommerce templates/content-single-product.php file shows the hook priorities for the single product loop.

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook
>   -https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html