# header.php | Change position of search

Tags: php, wordpress, css

How can i make the **search** come in between **storefront_primary_navigation** and **storefront_header_cart** on the 2nd line of header ?? using the below PHP code. if i make these changes in CSS, it looks ugly on the mobile devices. So can this be done in PHP ? If Yes, in which file should i make the changes and what are the changes ?

**Right now i have two lines in header:**
First Line: Logo | secondary_navigation | product_search
Second Line: primary_navigation | header_cart

**Now the header looks like:**
[image]

PHP:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" <?php if ( get_header_image() != '' ) { echo 'style="background-image: url(' . esc_url( get_header_image() ) . ');"'; } ?>>
        <div class="col-full">

            <?php
            /**
             * @hooked storefront_skip_links - 0
             * @hooked storefront_social_icons - 5
             * @hooked storefront_site_branding - 10
             * @hooked storefront_secondary_navigation - 15
             * @hooked storefront_product_search - 20
             * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation - 25
             * @hooked storefront_header_cart - 30
             */
            do_action( 'storefront_header' ); ?>

        </div>
```

**Output needed:**
First Line: Logo | secondary_navigation
Second Line: primary_navigation  | product_search | header_cart

[image]

**Manoj Changes:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the action called 'storefront_header'. Search through your theme files for it. If you are using sublime text 2 and have the theme directory open you can use ctrl-shift-f to search through all files at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to question/answer here: [**Sample product, Change location of price**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541066/sample-product-change-location-of-price-wordpress-woocommerce/31541609?noredirect=1#comment51721472_31541609) and glad you commented on the answer there ;)

**PHP Edit:**

In the below code, you are overwriting the Storefront hook inclusion/priority order. So the `storefront_product_search` will be included after `storefront_primary_navigation` which has a priority value of 25.

Include the following code in `functions.php`.

```
remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 20 );

add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 26 );
```

**CSS Edit:**

```
.woocommerce-active .site-header .main-navigation {
  width: 58.913%; /* Changed to occupy the Search in same line */
}

.site-search:nth-of-type(1) {
   display: none; 
}
```

The second CSS rule is a hack to remove the first occurrence of the Search bar, it is not a standard solution. Since I don't have access to your PHP code, it is hard to predict the cause of the two search bar problem. There might be other actions interfering with the hook and undoing the remove_action PHP code or the priority was changed elsewhere.

**Output:**

[image: Woocommerce Search bar]

Comment: after i made the changes suggested by you, i am getting two search box'es as shown in the attached images..in the original question

Comment: Can you provide the link to your page/site?

Comment: Its the home page of ironware.in

Comment: Thank You for supporting, i am afraid to inform that this did not work. So basically i have 3 lines created now.. the new search bar comes in the 2nd line. Let me know an appropriate time to share my screen via Team Viewer..

Comment: Create a demo of your site, so that I can work on it. I will be off for sometime. I will come back and let you know the solution after checking the demo.